# Pretty URLs on BuddyPress members search

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

Searching the BuddyPress members directory without ajax enabled results in search URLs looking like this:

```
example.com/members/?s=searchterm
```

Is there a way have 'pretty' URLs such as:

```
example.com/members/searchterm
```

I have tried Mark Jaquith's Nice Search, but this doesn't work for the BuddyPress member search. It only works for WordPress search.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/nice-search/

Comment: Unfortunately I have not come across an answer for this. There seems to be very little information and questioning on the Internet. Additionally, without BuddyPress installed I can get Wordpress's /search/{search-term} to work properly. After installing BuddyPress any /search url gets redirected back to the home page.

Comment: I still haven't found an answer unfortunately. If I do, I'll provide an update. Additionally, BuddyPress is moving over to WordPress-style rewrite rules in version 2.1 so hopefully we'll have some joy then.